# How did I set up this USB multi-partition?

Tags: linux, windows-10, hard-drive, usb, partitioning

I have a Corsair Voyager GTX flash drive and I partitioned it to have four partitions, one of which I'm using for Kali Linux live, there other for my portable apps and portable gamestation folder and there other for storage and last one is hidden.

I got it working: lovely Kali Linux is bootable on my laptop through USB boot and Windows assigns drive paths to each one (except the hidden, of course). I'm stumped as to how I did this ... I know I used BOOTICE and DiskPart and nothing else (win32 disk install for Kali Live), and now when I try to replicate it for another drive (non Corsair GTX), it won't work. Is it because of the Voyager drive itself? or am I overlooking something? I noticed that the drive is reading as basic disk and not removable (and I can convert to dynamic). Any light shed would be helpful.

I am a college student and would love to replicate the method for other students without having to open bootice to set and unset accessibility.

Here's how Windows is recognizing the drive:

[image]

Comment: Could you make the question more readable by formatting into paragraphs?  Note that  I is always capitalized in English.  Periods break sentences not ellipsis

Comment: I'am sorry about that, so my question is how is it possible to make a usb flash drive read as 4 separate paths as i have done shown in the picture? I have currently forgot how to do it and when trying to replicate the result on another flash drive it wont work. Is it because of the drive itself, or in order to do so again do i actually have to use the "flip" method of changing "removable" id?

Comment: We can't tell you how *you* did something.  But I typically use GParted to partition my flash drives.

Comment: I believe Windows cannot handle multiple partitions on removable drive (it's up to *removable bit*), while Linux doesn't care. Check [this Google search](https://www.google.pl/search?q=flip+removable+bit) and [this Super User search](https://superuser.com/search?q=multiple+partitions+USB). The main reason people need to flip the bit is to make Windows use more than one partition on the drive. I've seen reports that very few flash drives allow flipping the bit with some fancy tool; most don't.

Comment: You can use [YUMI](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) to create multiboot USB drive where you can store your files.

Comment: Is it possible when installing kali linux (actual install and not running live) it tricked the usb into believing it was a disk , and then i was able to do the partitions correctly through bootice? Sorry , ill give it a shot later after finals to confirm , if no luck ill blame it on the drive itself since it has an ssd controller in it supposedly.  Guy's first and forth most i'd like to thank you , this is my first time posting anything on any forum and i tend to be the "tinker until you get it right " type , but having the courtesy of you guys exploring such a silly question given humbles me.